# yield and include isnt working in laravel?

Tags: laravel, yield

in `backend/info.blade.php` i have two sections:

```
@section('info');
code
@endsection;
@section('status');
code
@endsection;
```

How can I include these in my `home.blade.php` (the first page the user see)? I have tried
`<span class="open">@yield('status')</span>` but it don't work. I have tried having @include('backend.info') on the top of the `home.blade.php` but this just adds the `info.blade.php` above everything else, not where the `@yield` are.

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is my first laravel project, I'm trying to learn, but I didn't find/understand the documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

So that's actually not how this works.

The yield field should be used on a template parent, like `layouts/app.blade.php`,
then a page that's extending it via `@extends('layouts.app')` could include the `@section` tags.

Comment: ok, I must have misunderstood. but what is the best way to include some part of my code, (what I originally had inside `@section('info')` and `@section('status')`) inside the `home.blade.php` file?

Comment: You could include the `backend.info` and pass in variables

Comment: I understand, but the reason I used `@sections` in the first place was that this is a PHP file and the result isn't a one variable, I uses `@sections` to display different sections of the code. Hope that makes sense.